# nvm use not working - what is setting node version to 10?

Tags: node.js

I am running a node proxy server. I recently tried to update it to use some functionality only available in the latest Node (Promise.any). But somehow I can't get it to run with that version after deploying the code to the host.

I run these commands:

```
nvm use 15
node version.js
sudo node dist/proxy.js
```

version.js just contains this code:

```
console.log(`node v${process.versions.node}`);
```

And the same code is inside proxy.js, more or less:

```
logger.info(`[proxy service] node v${process.versions.node}`);
```

This is the output:

`node v15.14.0`

`[11:44:35.198]<info> [proxy service] node v10.15.1`

I am completely bewildered as to how the proxy is running under v10 and the version program under 15. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo node version.js`? Or `sudo nvm use 15` followed by those other lines?

Comment: Indeed that is the clue @JLRishe. I cannot do sudo nvm (nvm not found), but sudo node version.js gives me v10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a minute when you do

nvm use 15

You do it with a normal user, but when you run the code

sudo node dist/proxy.js

Who executes that is not the same user that ran nvm use 15,
The problem is that root has version 10 and normal user has version 15.

You need to sudo nvm use 15, but it is better if you run yow code without sudo